# Highlight duplicate numbers if it occurs more than once in excel

Tags: excel, formula

Can someone please give a detailed explanation of how to do this.
I'm given a data set containing over 8000+ numbers. They are either 0 or 1 listed in the first column, 'A.' I'd like to know a formula for how to highlight any 0's if they occur 6 or more times consecutively.

I've used =Countif($A$1:A1,A1)>3 as an example, but it doesn't work. Just highlights some of the 0's. Example of what I'd like.

**A1: 0**

**A2: 0**

A3: 1

A4: 0

A5: 1

**A6: 0**

**A7: 0**

**A8: 0**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Select from cell A6 down to the end of the column. Create a conditional format with this formu.a:

```
=OR(SUM(A1:A6)=0,SUM(A2:A7)=0,SUM(A3:A8)=0,SUM(A4:A9)=0,SUM(A5:A10)=0,SUM(A6:A11)=0)
```

[image]